# Resizing TBitmap with alpha channel in Delphi

Tags: delphi, transparency, image-scaling

I have a `TBitmap` in Delphi with alpha channel. It comes from loading a PNG with a TPNGImage and then extracting the TBitmap.

This works perfectly.

Now, I want to scale this TBitmap, and I found that `scaledraw` has low quality and does not handle transparency, so I downloaded the Image32 library ( https://github.com/AngusJohnson/Image32 )

The code looks like:

```
  var inBitmap: TImage32 := TImage32.Create;
  var outBitmap: TBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  
  try
    inBitmap.CopyFromBitmap(inPict.Bitmap);

    inBitmap.Resampler := rBicubicResampler;
    inBitmap.Resize(scale.Width, scale.Height); // New size
    inBitmap.Crop(newRect); // Take only the required part.

    outBitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit; // I think it's not required
    inBitmap.CopyToBitmap(outBitmap);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(inBitmap);
    FreeAndNil(outBitmap);
  end;
```

This seems to work fine on Lazarus FPC, but not on Delphi: the image is scaled, but have weird artifacts:

Before scaled, drawn on top of a flat color:

[image]

After scaled, drawn on top of the same flat color:

[image]

Note, for drawing, I use the following line:

```
Canvas.Draw(x, y, outBitmap);
```

---

**How to properly scale the TBitmap with transparency?** (Must be cross-platform with Lazarus/FPC and Linux)

A full project can be found here:

https://github.com/Escain/TestImage32

Answer (score -1):

I'm confident that this issue isn't in the Image32 library.
See the discussion here:
https://github.com/AngusJohnson/Image32/issues/30

Comment: I don't think this answer the question, does it?